# Есть ли в ячейке комментарий?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы после добавления комментария в ячейку гугл-таблицы, например О2, сработало условное форматирование?
Вообщем, какая функция проверяет наличие комментария в ячейке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочтите подробный ответ на аналогичный вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556476/google-apps-script-spreadsheet-comment-automation). Таким образом, Вы **не можете** программно управлять комментариями (comments), но можете делать это в отношении замечаний (notes).

Условное форматирование трудно заставить реагировать на наличие комментария или замечания напрямую, так как оно анализирует результат вычислений (значение в ячейке). Поэтому можно порекомендовать поэтапное решение вопроса. Допустим, надо применить условное форматирование для ячеек A1:A100 (цвет при наличии замечания).

```
function onChange(e) {
  var sht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var notes = sht.getRange('A1:A100').getNotes();
  sht.getRange('B1:B100').setValues(notes);
}
```

1. Создайте дополнительную пустую колонку (скажем, B) для перевода замечаний в значения ячеек. Позднее её можно будет скрыть.
2. Создайте функцию для отображения замечаний из колонки A в значения колонки B, как показано выше. Название функции может быть другим, это не ключевое слово.
3. Установите [триггер **change**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) для этой функции и убедитесь в том, что он запускает функцию при каждом добавлении/изменении/удалении замечания.
4. Задайте условное форматирование для колонки A на основании значений из колонки B, как показано на рисунке.

[image: Условное форматирование для ячеек колонки A]

Не могу гарантировать, что этот приём годится для *всех* случаев использования формул в колонке A, но для простых значений и, собственно, замечаний он работает.